# Is it possible to update stackdriver logs when a BigQuery job completes?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, stackdriver

I am using the BigQuery Python library to submit a query job. In stackdriver i can see that the job was submitted, but I would like to see a log entry in Stackdriver when the job is complete. Is this possible to setup?

I know that you can poll the job_id to see the status, but the job runs longer than my cloud function can stay alive.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what u need as it talks about dataflow but it might put you in the right direction https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring

Answer (score 2):

StackDriver already shows this information to users:

[image]

[image]